# How to edit squid.conf file in notepad/gedit without using vi editor

Tags: 11.10

I have installed squid proxy server and I want to edit the `squid.conf` file with gedit. I dont want to use vi editor. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you have GUI , then you can use

```
gksu gedit <path to your file>
```

If its a server with no GUI then you can use nano .

```
sudo nano <path to your file name>
```

Gedit is one of the GUI editor and nano is one of the CLI editor.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder containing the file and run `gedit squid.conf` or alternatively run `gksu gedit squid.conf` to run it with super user privileges.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer that has answer to the question (Jai's is the superior answer here).